# Restoring Box Sync (box.com) using physical media after OS reinstall

Tags: cloud, box.com

I have my Box Folder on a different drive ( D: ) than my Operating System Drive ( C: )

I follow these instructions to set the local folder on the second drive.
https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200852947-How-Can-I-Change-the-Default-Folder-Location-for-Box-Sync-

I had to format and reinstall Windows 7, leaving the other drive (D: ) untouched.
now i reinstalled Box Sync, and directed it to the same location where i already have all my files. However, Box Sync renamed the folder to (Box (xxxxxx@gmail.com) ) as a bckup, and is downloading everything again.

As i have like 30Gb of files, and it takes many hour to download them, i just want to use the files that i already have in my local disk.
i tried copying all files again to the new local Box Folder, but files started to get duplicated.

Is there any way to avoid downloading everything again each time i reinstall my OS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

I have had this exact scenario today when migrating to a new Mac, and have established in a support interaction with box support that there's no way to tell box sync that the local files you have sitting right there on your machine are the same ones it's insisting on re-downloading.

Quite frustrating, and different behaviour to dropbox in this scenario.